# How to remove values in a certain range in csv files

Tags: csv, file, range

I have a CSV file with coordinates and values and i want to filter it over a certain range, with 157<x<480.

I tried this

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree
import csv
import sys
import os
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

meanflowdata='fieldlp3.csv' #'../Mean Flow Data/hcmd_3_100000.csv'
f=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(meanflowdata))
outputfile=f[0]+'_cut' + f[1]
xd=[]
yd=[]
zd=[]
cd=[]
rhod=[]
range_start=157.0
range_end=480.0
with open(meanflowdata,'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in spamreader:
        if len(row)>2:
            mask = np.logical_and(float(row[0])>=range_start, float(row[0])<=range_end)
            rows = 
            xd.append(float(row[0]))
            yd.append(float(row[1]))
            zd.append(float(row[2]))
            rhod.append(float(row[3]))
            cd.append(float(row[4]))
            
Xd=np.sort(np.asarray([xd,yd,zd,cd,rhod]))

print         
mask = np.logical_and(Xd.T[:,0]>=range_start, Xd.T[:,0]<=range_end)
xd =  Xd.T[:,0][mask]

print "# Writing output"
with open(outputfile, 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for i in range(len(xd)):    
       spamwriter.writerow([str(xd[i]),str(yd[i]),str(zd[i]),str(cd[i]),str(rhod[i])])
```

but like that it takes the right values for the X coordinate and the wrong values for the other variables. Is there a way to select in the csv file only rows between my range and wiriting them back on another file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly whats your expected output is or how your csv file looks like, so I can't give you an exact code to use, but this code generally does what you want:

```
import csv

range_start = 157.0
range_end = 480.0

with open("meanflowdata", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open("new_meanflowdata.csv", "w") as new_csv_file:
        fieldnames = ["x_coor", "y_coor"]

        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        csv_writer.writeheader()

        for line in csv_reader:
            if line["x_coor"] <= range_start or line["x_coor"] >= range_end:
                del line["x_coor"]

            elif line["y_coor"] <= range_start or line["y_coor"] >= range_end:
                del line["y_coor"]

            csv_writer.writerow(line)
```